# Adapt css style from a website to a Django crispy form checkbox

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap, I have a Django crispy form with a checkbox in it, the html looks like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox" id="div_id_include">
            <label class="" for="id_include"><input class="checkboxinput" id="id_include" name="include" type="checkbox"> Include some data.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am having trouble adapting the following css classes to this rendered html, the checkbox is completely opaque and is not visible when the following css is applied:

**CSS**

```
.checkbox-wrapper {
position: relative;
}

td .checkbox-wrapper, th .checkbox-wrapper {
    margin: 0 0 0 6px;
}

.checkbox, input[type=checkbox].checkbox, .checkbox-styled {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #d3dbe2;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkbox, input[type=checkbox].checkbox {
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0
}

.checkbox-styled {
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 1
}

.checkbox-styled:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.15s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2
}

.checkbox:active ~ .checkbox-styled, .checkbox:focus ~ .checkbox-styled {
    border-color: #479ccf
}

.checkbox:checked ~ .checkbox-styled:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)
}

.checkbox:indeterminate ~ .checkbox-styled:after {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)
    }

.checkbox-styled:after {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-        ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2024%2024%22%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3Ecircle%2Cellipse%2Cline%2Cpath%2Cpolygon%2Cpolyline%2Crect%2Ctext%7Bfill%3A%23479ccf%20%21important%3B%20%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M23.6%205L22%203.4c-.5-.4-1.2-.4-1.7%200L8.5%2015l-4.8-4.7c-.5-.4-1.2-.4-1.7%200L.3%2011.9c-.5.4-.5%201.2%200%201.6l7.3%207.1c.5.4%201.2.4%201.7%200l14.3-14c.5-.4.5-1.1%200-1.6z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E)
}

.checkbox:indeterminate ~ .checkbox-styled:after {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2012%2012%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2012%2012%22%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3Ecircle%2Cellipse%2Cline%2Cpath%2Cpolygon%2Cpolyline%2Crect%2Ctext%7Bfill%3A%23479ccf%20%21important%3B%20%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M6%200%22%2F%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M.8%207C.3%207%200%206.7%200%206.2v-.4c0-.5.3-.8.8-.8h10.5c.4%200%20.7.3.7.8v.5c0%20.4-.3.7-.8.7H.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E)
}
```

**The style is from here: [Shopify embedded app css](http://seaff.microapps.com/) (where you can also see examples of the checkbox).**

If have this working when I don't use Crispy forms but I output the html directly (within a table row):

```
<td>
    <div class="checkbox-wrapper"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="id" name="" value="id"><span class="checkbox-styled"></span></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Do you have control over the Crispy output?

Comment: fairly limited control, I can wrap the entire form-group in a div, or include a css_class for input checkboxinput. Alternatively, I technically can write my own template to format the form field a specific way (I have just never tried this before). I am not very good at applying css though after the fact, and have been having trouble applying that css to even a default bootstrap checkbox (without my crispy form layout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there was no lazy way to do this. I solved this by ensuring that I followed the html layout provided by the embedded app css that I referenced in my post, and then customzing my crispy forms field template for checkboxes to ensure that it rendered html with the correct layout:

```
<div class="input-wrapper inline">
  <div class="checkbox-wrapper"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value=""><span class="checkbox-styled"></span></div>
  <label for="check1">Check 1</label>
</div>
```